# Unable to check and validate UserId(username) already existing in database via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I don't know why my code is not working. I want to validate the user already exists error in a registration form in register.php all my code are perfectly working in user.php and process.php but it doesn't redirect to register.php when i tried to register with already existing userid(username), nothing happens and when i tried to register with new  userid(username) the data are stored in database but it doesn't redirect to index.php what is the problem here please help me. I also have published my code in github the link is: https://github.com/bloodseeker2018/inv_project
Please help me what's wrong with my code. I have searched everthing that i can do.
The thing i want to do is that if anyone tries to register with new user it should alert user already exists and if anyone tries to register with new user id (username) it stores in database and redirect to index.php
please help me.. I would be very greatful if anyone help me.
the register.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
        <title> Inventory Management System </title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/validation.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    </head>
<body>
<?php //Navbar
include_once("./templates/header.php");
?>
<br/><br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card mx-auto shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="width: 25rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Add Users</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="register_form" name="register_form"  method="post" action="register.php">
                    <div class="form-group mx-auto">                
                        <label for="fullname">Full Name*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-info-circle" ><span class="infotext">Your First Name and Last Name should be minimum of 3 character</span></i>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">                                      
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20" data-validation="required" />
                                <span id="error_firstname" class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12px;"></span>                 
                            </div>                          
                            <div class="col-md-6">  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="20" data-validation="required"/>                           
                                <span id="error_lastname" class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12px;"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group mx-auto">
                        <label for="username">User Id*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="userid form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="This will be your login User Id" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"/>                              
                        <span id="error_username" class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12px;"></span>                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-auto">
                        <label for="password1">Password*</label>
                        <input type="password" class="password1 form-control" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="Password">   
                        <input type="checkbox" id="showHide"/>
                        <label for="showHide" id="showHideLabel"><font class="form-text text-muted" size="2">Show Password</font></label><br/>
                        <span id="error_password1" class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12px;"></span>                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Password2">Re-Enter Password*</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Re-type your Password">
                        <span id="error_password2" class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12px;" ></span>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usertype">User Type*</label>
                        <select name="usertype" class="form-control" id="usertype">
                            <option value="" selected="selected" hidden disabled="disabled">Select</option>                         
                            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>                                
                            <option value="Normal_User">Normal User</option>                            
                        </select>
                        <span id="error_usertype" class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12px;"></span>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus">&nbsp;</i>Add</button>
                    </div>

        <!--            <button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #008000"><i class="fa fa-unlock">&nbsp;</i><span><a href="index.php" style="color: white; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 100; font-family: sans-serif;"> Login</span></button>  -->
                </form>
            </div>      
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">Please fill in all the compulsory(*) fields above
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The index.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
        <title> Inventory Management System </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php //Navbar
        include_once("./templates/homeheader.php");
        ?>
    </br></br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card mx-auto shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded " id="firstclass" style="width:20rem;">
                <br/>
                <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" style="width: 60%;" src="./images/adbl.png" id="LoginIcon">
                <div class="card-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username">User ID</label>
                                     <div class="input-container">
                                    <input type="text" class="username form-control" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Input your Username">  
                                    </div>                          
                                    <small id="textHelp" class="form-text text-muted"> We'll never share your User Id with anyone else.</small>
                                </div>      
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="Password"> Password </label>
                                    <input type="password" name="Password" class="password form-control" placeholder="Password">                        
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="showHide"> 
                                    <label for="showHide" id="showHideLabel"><font class="form text text-muted"size="2" > Show Password </font></label>                                         
                                </div>                                  
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-unlock">&nbsp;</i>Login</button>
                            </form>
                </div>             
                <div class="card-footer"><a href="http://localhost/inv_project/public_html/register.php#">Forgot Password ?</a></div>
            </div>          
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

The validation.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var DOMAIN = "http://localhost/inv_project/public_html";
    $flag = 1;
    function validateFirstname(sFirstname) {
        var filter = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
        if (filter.test(sFirstname)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#firstname").focusout(function () {
        var sFirstname = $('#firstname').val();
        if ($.trim(sFirstname).length == 0) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_firstname").text("Enter your First Name");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 3 ) {
                 $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
                 $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                 $("#error_firstname").text("Too short First Name");
        } else if (validateFirstname(sFirstname)) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#error_firstname").text("");;
        } else {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_firstname").text("Invalid First Name");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    function validateLastname(sLastname) {
        var filter1 = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
        if (filter1.test(sLastname)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#lastname").focusout(function () {
        var sLastname = $('#lastname').val();
        if ($.trim(sLastname).length == 0) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_lastname").text("Enter your Last Name");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 3 ) {
                 $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
                 $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                 $("#error_lastname").text("Too short Last Name");
        } else if (validateLastname(sLastname)) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#error_lastname").text("");;
        } else {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_lastname").text("Invalid Last Name");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    function validateUsername(sUsername) {
        var filter2 = /^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]+(([\.-]?)[a-z0-9]+)*(([\._]?)[a-z0-9]+)*(([\_-]?)[a-z0-9]+)*$/;
        if (filter2.test(sUsername)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#username").focusout(function () {
        var sUsername = $('#username').val();
        if ($.trim(sUsername).length == 0) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_username").text("Enter your User Id");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 7 ) {
                 $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
                 $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                 $("#error_username").text("Too short User Id");
        } else if (validateUsername(sUsername)) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#error_username").text("");;
        } else {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_username").text("Invalid User Id");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    function validateUsertype(){
        if (document.register_form.usertype.value == ""){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    $("#usertype").focusout(function () {
        if (!validateUsertype()){
                $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                $("#error_usertype").text("Select a User Type");
            } else {
                $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                $("#error_usertype").text("");
        }
    });
    function validatePassword(sPassword) {
        var filter3 = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/;
        if (filter3.test(sPassword)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#password1").focusout(function () {
        var sPassword = $('#password1').val();
        if ($.trim(sPassword).length == 0) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_password1").text("Enter a Password");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if ($(this).val().length < 9 ) {
                 $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
                 $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                 $("#error_password1").text("Too short Password");
        } else if (validatePassword(sPassword)) {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
            $("#error_password1").text("");;
        } else {
            $(this).css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_password1").text("Invalid Password");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $("#password2").focusout(function () {
        var sPassword = $('#password1').val();
        if (validatePassword(sPassword)){
            if ($("#password2").val() !== $("#password1").val()) {
                $("#password2").css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                $("#error_password2").text("Passwords Do not match");
            } else if (($("#password2").val() == $("#password1").val()) && $("#password1").val() !== '') {
                $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                $("#error_password2").text("");
            }
        } else if (!validatePassword(sPassword)){
                $("#password2").css("border-color", "");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                $("#error_password2").text("");
                $("#password2").val('');       
        }
    });

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        if ($("#firstname").val() == '') {
            $("#firstname").css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true); 
            $("#error_firstname").text("Enter your First Name"); 
        }
        if ($("#lastname").val() == '') {
            $("#lastname").css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_lastname").text("Enter your Last Name");
        }
        if ($("#username").val() == '') {
            $("#username").css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_username").text("Enter your User Id");
        }
        if ($("#password1").val() == '') {
            $("#password1").css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_password1").text("Enter a Password");
        }
        if (!validateUsertype()){
                $("#usertype").css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                $("#error_usertype").text("Select a User Type");
        }
        if ($("#password2").val() == '' && $("#password1").val() !== '') {
            $("#password2").css("border-color", "#cd2d00");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_password2").text("Confirm your Password");
        } else if (validatePassword($("#password1").val())){
              if (!($('#submit').is('disabled', true))){ 
                if (($("#password2").val() == $("#password1").val()) && $("#password1").val() !== '') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : DOMAIN+"/includes/process.php",
                        method : "POST",
                        data : $("#register_form").serialize(),
                        success : function(data){
                            if (data == "USER_ALREADY_EXISTS"){
                                alert("User Id is already used");
                            } else if (data == "SOME_ERROR"){
                                alert("Something is Wrong");
                            }else {
                                window.location.href = encodeURI(DOMAIN+"/index.php?msg=You are registered Now you can login");
                            }
                        }

                    })                
                } 
            }
        }
    })   
});
```

The main.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showHide").click(function(){
        if ($(".password1").attr("type")=="password"){
            $(".password1").attr("type","text");
        } else {
            $(".password1").attr("type","password");
        }                           
    });
    $("#showHide").click(function(){
        if ($(".password").attr("type")=="password"){
            $(".password").attr("type","text")
        } else {
            $(".password").attr("type","password")
        }                           
    });

    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("slow");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
        },
        function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
        });
});
```

The process.php is:

```
<?php
include_once("../database/constants.php");
include_once("user.php");
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
    $user = new User();
    $result = $user->createUserAccount($_POST["username"],$_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"],$_POST["password1"],$_POST["usertype"]);
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

The user.php is:

```
<?php
class User
{
    private $con;
    function __construct()
    {   
        include_once("../database/db.php");
        $db = new Database();
        $this->con = $db->connect();    
    }
    private function usernameExists($username){
        $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `user` where `username` = ?");
        $pre_stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
        $result = $pre_stmt->get_result();      
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
            return 1;       
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public function createUserAccount($username,$firstname,$lastname,$password1,$usertype){
        if($this->usernameExists($username)){
            return "USER_ALREADY_EXISTS";
        }else{
            $pass_hash = password_hash($password1,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,["cost"=>8]);
            $date = date("Y-m-d");
            $remarks ="";
            $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`username`,`firstname`, `lastname`, `password`, `usertype`, `register_date`, `last_login`, `remarks`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $pre_stmt->bind_param("ssssssss",$username,$firstname,$lastname,$pass_hash,$usertype,$date,$date,$remarks);
            $result = $pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
            if ($result){
                return $this->con->insert_id;
            }else{
                return "SOME_ERROR";
            }
        }       
    }
    public function userLogin($username,$password1){
        $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id,username,firstname,lastname,password,usertype,last_login FROM user WHERE username = ?");
        $pre_stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
        $result = $pre_stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows < 1){
            return "NOT_REGISTERED";
        }else{
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if (password_verify($password1,$row["password"])){
                $_SESSION["userid"] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
                $_SESSION["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
                $_SESSION["usertype"] = $row["usertype"];
                $_SESSION["last_login"] = $row["last_login"];
                $last_login = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
                $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE user  SET last_login = ? WHERE username = ?");
                $pre_stmt->bind_param("ss",$last_login,$username);
                $result = $pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
                if ($result){
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }else{
                return "PASSWORD_NOT_MATCHED";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The constants.php is:

```
<?php

session_start();
define("HOST","localhost");
define("USER","root");
define("PASS","");
define("DB","project_inv");
define("DOMAIN","http://localhost/inv_project/public_html");


?>
```

The db.php is:

```
<?php


class Database
{
    private $con;

    public function connect(){
        include_once("constants.php");
        $this->con = new Mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
        if ($this->con) {           
            return $this->con;
        }       
        return "DATABASE_CONNECTION_FAIL";      
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Please help me with this one. I am in great need. if you want more code i have provided you with github link. please help me or i cant post other code if anyone wants

Comment: #Stackoverflow please help me with this one

Comment: Can't anyone do this.......from STACKOVERFLOW